# PROJ.4: Supported datums in TOWGS84

Tags: proj

TOWGS84 in PROJ.4 support datums transformation from another datum to WGS84 datum.

Could anyone please give me the list of datums which supported in this method.

Answer (score 2):

The `+towgs84` parameter accepts 3 or 7 double precision values describing the datum transformation. If you want to assign datum by name, you have to use `+datum`, i.e `+datum=clrk80`. Complete lists of datums and their names are located in `nad/` directory of Proj4 in files EPSG, world, ESRI, etc.